# Object(...)().signInUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function .... on trying to login user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Iam trying to authenticate the user for react chat app , all the other functions such as signup , signup with google are all working fine but when ever I try to login with already present account it shows

**Object(...)().signInUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function**

my authentication file code is this

```
import {auth} from "./firebase";


export function signup(email,password){
    return auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
}

export function signin(email,password){
    return auth().signInUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
}

export function signInWithGoogle(){
    const provider= new auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    return auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
}

export function signInWithGithub(){
    const provider= new auth.GithubAuthProvider()
    return auth().signInWithPopup(provider)

}

export function logout(){
    return auth().signOut();
}
```

**My firebase file**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/database'

const firebaseConfig = {
    //Hide keys
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  export default firebase;
  export  const auth = firebase.auth;
  export const db = firebase.database();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the this [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/user-authentication-firebase-react-apps/) of firebase auth with react js :

I think there is no functions like `signInUserWithEmailAndPassword` there is function with `signInWithEmailAndPassword` .

Comment: yeah all the other functionalities are working fine ,Iam only facing this problem in login

Comment: @Codewizard your function name changed just change with mine

Answer (score 2):

The method you're looking for is [signInWithEmailAndPassword()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword).

```
export function signin(email,password){
    return auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
}
```